# ImageView con Contador de Notificaciones Android Java

Tags: java, android

Quisiera saber si existe algun control , libreria o si lo tengo que hacer a mano , para poder implmentar un contador en un imageview , a lo que me refiero es , necesito replicar algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me refiero  a la imagen con un circulo rojo que dice 1..2..3.., etc ,
Actualmente tengo mi RecyclerView

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/lstMovsWallet"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@color/background_dark_grey"
                android:layout_below="@+id/strLblTitleMovs"/>
```

con mi adaptador perzonalizado

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white">
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNumberPhoneBilling"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDateBillingRef"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNumberPhoneBilling"
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:maxLines="1" />
<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
    android:id="@+id/txtDateBillingNotifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtNumberPhoneBilling"
    android:text="3"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/txtMountBillingNotifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNumberPhoneBilling"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDateBillingRef"
    android:text="4"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/IMGPerson"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnCancelBillingNotifications"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Como veran tengo una imagen de cada lado pero ahora mirando para poder poner esa imagen ahi arriba podria hacerlo manualmente agregando una imagen e ir centrandola pero quisiera saber si existe alguna forma mas confortante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo a mano usando por ejemplo un `FrameLayout` y un par de `ImageView`, una para la imagen y otra para el badge (esto es practicamente lo que estás haciendo).

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="30dp" 
    android:layout_height=30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IMGperson"
        ... />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnCancelBillingNotifications"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        ... />

</FrameLayout>
```

O puedes usar [DrawableBadge](https://github.com/minibugdev/DrawableBadge)

Comment: muchas gracias , investigare si utilizare la libreria o lo hago a mano gracias